# RaphaelJS polar chart text not drawing correctly

Tags: javascript, charts, raphael

I have the following code with which I am trying to draw a polar chart (as per http://www.maani.us/xml_charts/index.php?menu=Gallery&submenu=Polar):

```
var step = 360 / (c.chart_data[0][0].length - 1);
for (var i = 1; i < c.chart_data[0][0].length; i++) {
   paper.path([
      "M", c.chart_rect.x + c.chart_rect.width / 2, c.chart_rect.y + c.chart_rect.height / 2,
      c.chart_rect.x + c.chart_rect.width / 2 + (Math.cos(step * (i-1) * (Math.PI/180)) * (c.chart_rect.height / 2)),
      c.chart_rect.y + c.chart_rect.height / 2 + (Math.sin(step * (i-1) * (Math.PI/180)) * (c.chart_rect.height / 2))
   ]).attr({
      "stroke-width": c.chart_grid_v.thickness,
      stroke: c.chart_grid_v.color,
      "stroke-opacity": c.chart_grid_v.alpha,
      "stroke-dasharray": c.chart_grid_v.type
   });

   var text = paper.text(0, 0, c.chart_data[0][0][i]);
   text.attr({"font-size": c.axis_category.size, "font-family": c.axis_category.font, "font-weight": c.axis_category.bold});
   text.attr({fill: c.axis_category.color, opacity: c.axis_category.alpha});
   // Text is draw centered at x, y by default.
   text.transform("r" + (step * (i-1)).toString());
   text.translate(c.chart_rect.x + c.chart_rect.width / 2 + (Math.cos(step * (i-1) * (Math.PI/180)) * (c.chart_rect.height / 2 + 10)),
      c.chart_rect.y + c.chart_rect.height / 2 + (Math.sin(step * (i-1) * (Math.PI/180)) * (c.chart_rect.height / 2 + 10)));
}
```

where `chart_data` refers to:

```
chart_data: [
                           // Quartiles data.
                           [
                              [null, "North", "", "North\nEast", "", "East", "", "South\nEast", "",
                               "South", "", "South\nWest", "", "West", "", "North\nWest", ""],
                              ["Summer", 12, 15, 20, 15, 10, 7, 8, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 10, 10],
                              ["Autumn", 10, 10, 15, 25, 30, 35, 32, 30, 25, 22, 18, 10, 8, 5, 7, 10],
                              ["Winter", 10, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 40, 30, 30, 25, 20, 10, 10, 10],
                              ["Spring", 2, 10, 15, 15, 20, 25, 25, 22, 20, 15, 10, 12, 10, 7, 5, 3]
                           ]
                        ],
```

The radial grid lines work correctly, but the text at the end of those radial lines don't work. The transform seems to be adding to the previous transform. If I clear the transform with `transform("")` that also doesn't work, instead just printing all the text on top of each other.

When I plot the results of

```
c.chart_rect.x + c.chart_rect.width / 2 + (Math.cos(step * (i-1) * (Math.PI/180)) * (c.chart_rect.height / 2 + 10)),
            c.chart_rect.y + c.chart_rect.height / 2 + (Math.sin(step * (i-1) * (Math.PI/180)) * (c.chart_rect.height / 2 + 10))
```

in Excel they correctly form a circle.

I also need to use `text.getBBox().height` to offset the text further, which causes further complications.

Does someone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Too much code and info without breaking it down. You may want to try R rather than r (absolute vs relative) for the transforms, you may also want to use transform instead of translate (I think translate is deprecated), eg 'T20,40R45' as example transform string.

Comment: R for some reason has the same result as r.

Comment: I would put a minimal testing example on a jsfiddle so people can examine it properly.

Comment: Made this http://jsfiddle.net/Superdooperhero/byu3a5ou/1/ but for some reason it doesn't do anything. Don't know jsfiddle unfortunately.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/byu3a5ou/2/ thats the fiddle with the errors fixed, not sure if thats what you are wanting to show to highlight the problem you are having ?

Comment: Yeah that's the fiddle that shows the problem